# Swift parsing JSON response

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, foursquare

I need to parsing a JSON response from Foursquare API, I'm using swift:

I have the code to make an API request and I get the following response:

```
Optional({"meta":{"code":200,"requestId":"56d2a675498e93c71cfeadc5"},"response":{"venues":[{"id":"4f629435e4b086a33576e89e","name":"El Rinconcito Poblano","contact":{},"location":{"lat":16.735342,"lng":-92.038453,"distance":21267,"cc":"MX","country":"Mexico","formattedAddress":["Mexico"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1c1941735","name":"Mexican Restaurant","pluralName":"Mexican Restaurants","shortName":"Mexican","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/mexican_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":10,"usersCount":8,"tipCount":0},"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Nobody here","groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1456645749","venueChains":[]},{"id":"502aae9de4b059b606a00f7d","name":"Mariscos","contact":{},"location":{"lat":16.73153051714288,"lng":-92.04085495810608,"distance":21313,"cc":"MX","country":"Mexico","formattedAddress":["Mexico"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d1ce941735","name":"Seafood Restaurant","pluralName":"Seafood Restaurants","shortName":"Seafood","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/seafood_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":2,"usersCount":2,"tipCount":0},"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Nobody here","groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1456645749","venueChains":[]},{"id":"51c47ba9498efee47ed447ce","name":"Tricos","contact":{},"location":{"address":"Justo Sierra","lat":16.543866,"lng":-92.055473,"distance":23967,"cc":"MX","country":"Mexico","formattedAddress":["Justo Sierra","Mexico"]},"categories":[{"id":"4bf58dd8d48988d112941735","name":"Juice Bar","pluralName":"Juice Bars","shortName":"Juice Bar","icon":{"prefix":"https:\/\/ss3.4sqi.net\/img\/categories_v2\/food\/juicebar_","suffix":".png"},"primary":true}],"verified":false,"stats":{"checkinsCount":0,"usersCount":0,"tipCount":0},"allowMenuUrlEdit":true,"specials":{"count":0,"items":[]},"hereNow":{"count":0,"summary":"Nobody here","groups":[]},"referralId":"v-1456645749","venueChains":[]},.....
```

I got in venues an array, how can I just get an array of names or pictures of each venue?

Thank you.

Comment: I would look into https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON to help you achieve that.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for a library for this it can be done just fine without it.

Here's one way of doing it with plain swift

```
protocol JSONDecodable {
    typealias DecodableType
    static func decode(data: [NSString: AnyObject]) throws -> DecodableType
    static func decode(array: [[NSString: AnyObject]]) -> [DecodableType]
}

enum DecodingError: ErrorType {
    case InvalidInstance(error: String)
}

struct Photo {
    let url: NSURL
}

struct Venue {
    let id: String
    let name: String
    let photos: [Photo]
}


extension Venue: JSONDecodable {
    typealias DecodableType = Venue
    static func decode(data: [NSString : AnyObject]) throws -> DecodableType {
        guard let id = data["id"] as? String,
            let name = data["name"] as? String else {
                throw DecodingError.InvalidInstance(error: "Keys `id` and `name` were not present and Strings")
        }

        return Venue(id: id, name: name, photos: [])
    }

    static func decode(array: [[NSString : AnyObject]]) -> [DecodableType] {
        return array.flatMap {
            try? Venue.decode($0)
        }
    }
}
```

I will leave implementing parsing of the photos as an exercise for you, but it's generally the same idea as parsing the Venue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Hugo, I think that I need more help. I have inside my viewController the locationManager function, with the following code I get the answer from Foursquare API: let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
            (data, response, error) in
            let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print(urlContent)   ////////// How can I use your code to parsing the variable "urlContent"

Comment: You don't want to be parsing the data as a string instead look at using [NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:) which will return either a dictionary or an array depending on the root of the json object